How to register trait with KryoSerializer in Spark scala?
I have a trait named as Strategy and then I have multiple scala singleton objects implementing this trait. Can we register the trait Strategy with KryoSerializer?
I tried using this but it doesn't work
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")
      .registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Strategy]))



is using kyro mandatory for you?  If normal encoders would work https://stackoverflow.com/a/78333976/1028537 provides a way to use frameless to handle adts

I am using a library and they have a trait which is not serializable. Now, when using that library in our code it's giving us error that TaskNotSerializable. So we decided to register that using Kryo

it'd be helpful if you could provide sample traits and objects exhibiting the problem
